# How to solve $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting this when trying to upload an image :

> $ is not a function

The error message comes from here:

```
$(document).height();
```

Comment: Put the code you try. and check the jquery is linked or not. $ sign is for recognize to the its an jquery funtion. when you change it to another key you cant access through the $ sign.

Comment: checked view source that you didn't add jquery file twice.. also jQuery file should be in head section

Comment: try pure js: `document.body.offsetHeight`

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported jQuery correctly? run this in the console to see if you get the version

```
   $().jquery;
```